# Cannot add reference for Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library to ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net

i have created a Website in ASP.NET using VB. I am trying to export a gridview to Excel using the Excel Interop.

When i try to add Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library to my site as a reference i get an error.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biU5K.png)

Can anybody help with this?

thanks

Gareth

Comment: Why are you trying to use Excel interop in an ASP.NET application? What do you need it for?

Comment: i am trying to export date from a gridview into Excel and then perform formatting on it etc. I used to use an activeX object but as Edge doesn't support it was looking for another way. Also the active X object takes an age when there is a lot of data

Comment: Okay - well the Excel interop libraries are [inappropriate to use](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) for that scenario. Instead, you should use a library capable of generating .xlsx docs without the need for interop, such as [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML), [EPPlus](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus), or [Aspose](https://products.aspose.com/cells/net).

Comment: Hi,i looked at EPPlus but it uses load from datatable, but there are no datatables in ASP.NET

Comment: Please take the time to do adequate research. EPPlus does *not* require datatables. There are plenty of ways of loading data into it that don't require datatables should you wish to not use them. I've even [blogged about it](https://masonmcg.com/Blog/entry/properly-generating-excel-files-in-net). And you're wrong - the [DataTable class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable) is part of the System.Data assembly, which is part of the .NET Framework, all of which can be consumed in an ASP.NET app.

Comment: Even if all of that weren't true - I also gave you 2 other libraries that are capable of doing what you need. Please take the time to adequately look into your options and select the best for your needs.

Comment: ok fairly new to this. I have used the Load from data reader method and all is now working as expected. thankk for you help with this

Answer (score 0):

using EPPLUS which works as i wanted